# Check if specific element in array contains a certain String. Then delete the element

Tags: java, arrays, string, arraylist

I have an ArrayList containing: [2x, 5, 6x]. I want to get rid of the elements containing the "x", but the contains() method applies to all of the elements in the ArrayList.

My attempt:

```
boolean ready = false;

while(!ready){
    if(first element in the array contains "x"){
    remove that element
    Check next element in line
}
```

When checked all the elements, and removed those which contains "x", set ready to true, and stop the loop. 
I want the output to just be: [6]. And then convert it to int, instead of String.

**EDIT:**
I couldn't get it to work with ArrayList, because I couldn't alter the contents of an ArrayList. Therefore I changed it to a simple array. 
The array is now: 
    String[]tokens = ligning2.split("-|\+|\*|\/");

So the tokens array will keep [2x, 5, 6x]. So how do I delete the elements containing an x, with this kind of Array, instead of Arraylist?

Comment: you'll need to post a new question and specify your latest problem, it's unlikely you'll get much attention with your latest edit.

Answer (score 0):

This would be a great opportunity to utilize a lambda when calling `List#removeIf`.

For example:

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("2x", "5", "6x");

System.out.println(list); // [2x, 5, 6x]

list.removeIf(element -> element.contains("x"));

System.out.println(list); // [5]
```

Assuming that there can be multiple values that remain in the `List` which did not contain an "x", you can use a `Stream` to map each element to its integer value:

```
List<Integer> newList = list.stream()
                            .map(Integer::valueOf)
                            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

The entire algorithm can be condensed into the following:

```
List<Integer> newList = list.stream()
                            .filter(element -> !element.contains("x"))
                            .map(Integer::valueOf)
                            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: @OusmaneMahyDiaw Why are you editing the spelling of words in my post when they are already correct?

Comment: apologise, I live in England hence I suggested that was the correct approach, I guess the US spelling is different. But note I also edited your code because it wouldn't compile had I left it as it was.

Comment: Yes, thank you for adding quotation marks.  And it's spelled "utilize" in the states ;)

Comment: @OusmaneMahyDiaw "[The belief that -ize is an exclusively American variant is incorrect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oxford_spelling)"

Answer (score 0):

Easiest thing to do is using `Stream`s. These were added in Java 8 and you can use them in your case to filter certain items from the list and convert them to integers in one run:

```
List<String> elements = Arrays.asList("2x", "5", "6x");
List<Double> result = elements.stream()
     .filter(entry -> !entry.contains("x"))
     .map(Double::valueOf) //this assumes that all other entries are valid doubles
     .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Thanks for the edits(instead of simply downvoting). Was quite in a hurry and didn't even notice those mistakes

Comment: note in java we use `->` but i can see where you got `=>` from (C#), also it's not `Collectors.asList()` but rather `Collectors.toList()`. It was probably a mistake which i do understand. I have edited it. +1.

Comment: I made a mistake to not to inform that it is not Integers, but I want to do it with double. Could you please change your code so it uses double instead of integers? I tried to change the list to Double, but gets an error at the `.collect(Collectors.toList());`

Comment: Edited my answer. The `Double` class also has the `valueOf` method which takes a string and tries to parse a double. Detailed documentation about what exactly this method accepts as a valid input can be found here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#valueOf-java.lang.String-

Answer (score 0):

- Use an iterator to iterate the List
- for each iteration, if the current `String` contains the "x" `String`, remove it from the `List` with `Iterator.remove();`

For example :

```
   for (Iterator<String> iterator = list.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
        String value = list.next();
        if(value.contains("x"){
           iterator.remove();
        }
    }
```

Comment: As I said to @JacobG, i get the following error: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException. I've taken a look at other people that have encountered this problem aswell, but their ArrayList is different than mine, since I split it up. Mine is: `List<String> asList = Arrays.asList(ligning2.split("-|\\+|\\*|\\/"));`

Comment: The JacobG solution cannot work. Don't mix  `Arrays.asList(..)` with `removeIf()` method. `Arrays.asList(..)` produces a no modifiable ArrayList. Create your list by using `new ArrayList()` Then iterate the array resulted from the split to populate the `ArrayList` with the `add(..)` method.

Comment: I'm more of a beginner, so if you could show me an example I'd be thrilled. 
I have the String variable containing lets say "2x+3". And I split it with `split("-|\\+|\\*|\\/")` How do I do it with the `new ArrayList()` instead of `Arrays.asList(..)` ? I am not sure what you mean by iterate.

Comment: I got an error if I didn't include the NodeList to the token, so I did so: `NodeList token = split("-|\\+|\\*|\\/");`. Next error I got is `for (String current : token)` which gives 
"foreach not applicable to expression type
    required: array or java.lang.literable
    found: NodeList"

Comment: `token` is indeed an array. Try that `String[] token = split("-|\\+|\\*|\\/"); List<String> list = new ArrayList(); for (String current : token){ list.add(current); }`

Comment: I'm not sure why it keeps insisting it's a NodeList. I get: incompatible types: NodeList cannot be converted to String[]

Comment: I honestly don't know. I'll see if I can find some answers online

Answer (score 0):

You can use an Iterator for example :

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("Hello", "xyz", "tkx");
Iterator<String> iter = list.iterator();
while (iter.hasNext()) {
    if(iter.next().contains("x")){//check if your element contain x
        iter.remove();//if yes remove it
    }
}
```

Comment: nice classic solution ^^.

Comment: @YCF_L How would you avoid the: UnsupportedOperationException error i get? I know why it's there, but I don't know how to avoid it. I've tried to use a 'normal' array, but I don't know what to do with that.

Comment: @Bassusour sorry for the late comment, what did you mean?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this program

```
package com.anand;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.ListIterator;

public class ArrayListRemove {
static ArrayList<String> al=new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("6x","8","5x"));
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Iterator<String> i=al.iterator();
    while(i.hasNext())
    {
        if(i.next().toString().contains("x"))
        {
            i.remove();
        }
    }
    ListIterator<String> li= al.listIterator();
    while(li.hasNext())
    {
        System.out.println(li.next());
    }

}

}
```

Please let me know of you want to create a new Arraylist of integers or just the output to be integers. I will make changes accordingly